# Is there a way I can record when the last time a piece of code was run?

Tags: apex, batch

I have written a Page and Controller which update a field in all Person Accounts in my org using a batch process. This is only meant to be done once a year. Is there a way I can record the last time the code was run, and warn someone if they do it too soon after the last time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could store every execution in a some sort of "Log" object, and query that object before the execution.

Comment: Once you have a log object like this, it becomes useful in many ways.  You can use it to track when a batch process last ran - and also capture some stats from that run.  I use it to track who uses a certain "mark problem solved" button.  I also use it to flag missing attendance and when the missing attendance is resolved.  I could go on.

Answer (score 0):

I actually used a Custom Setting which has just one record with one field which is the last time the code was run.